# How to fix iPhone no longer loading css on webpages and not connecting to internet

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

Currently my iPhone would not load the CSS parts on webpages so i.e. when I go to www.apple.com the phone would only load the words of the webpage

I cannot access apps such as Itune, Appstore, Facebook that utilizes the internet and basically the only thing that I can do is use the cellular call function,

Even then I cannot even send iMessage texts and send text messages either

When I try to update through iTunes on my Mac the update doesn't work, what should I do?

Comment: Is the clock on the device set correctly?

Comment: The reason for the CSS not loading is probably the fact that your internet isn't working as you probably got a cached version of the site. Have you tried a hardware reset (by pressing the home and power button at the same time for a few seconds until the phone turnes off)?

Comment: @Hoshts I resolved the problem

Comment: @grgarside thanks so much for the help, it turned out that when I did a time hack for a game I forgot to reset it

Comment: Excellent, I’ve given an answer with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the clock is set correctly on the device as this will prevent HTTPS.